# Difference between AD user inside the Users container and the ones created at the root

Tags: active-directory

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between a MS AD user created inside the Users Container and the ones that i can create, directly at the root of my domain?

I am kind of running into some issues with the authentication with the users that i created at the root

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The won't be any difference between users you create yourself in both places. However, the Users container is where the built-in user objects are, and there are differences between the built-in user objects and users you create yourself.

If you tell us what issues you're having, I might be able to help more.

Usually, your user accounts should go in an Organizational Unit (OU), since policies can be applied to those (policies cannot be applied to containers).